# Jquery add and remove several divs with one click

Tags: jquery

here is the code:

```
$('.add').click(function() {

var description = $('#description').val();
$(".append_data").append('<div class="row" style="background: #e6e6e6; color: #666; border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;"><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="1"></div><div class="col-md-5"><input type="text" name="2"></div><div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" name="3"></div><div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" name="4"></div></div><div class="remove">Remove</div>');

});

$('.append_data').on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
    //alert('boom');
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  return false;
});
```

Here is the code's Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/L7su5ke7/

It adds several divs , all right. But how I can delete those with one click - alas! I have not figured out ((
I have tried **"closest"** and **"parents"** both with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is that I enclosed that html code that you dynamically add with another `<div>`

```
$('.add').click(function() {

var description = $('#description').val();
$(".append_data").append('<div><div class="row" style="background: #e6e6e6; color: #666; border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;"><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="1"></div><div class="col-md-5"><input type="text" name="2"></div><div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" name="3"></div><div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" name="4"></div></div><div class="remove">Remove</div></div>');

});

$('.append_data').on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Then just removed the parent when the remove button is clicked!

Link: [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/L7su5ke7/5/)

Comment: Hails Akhilesh! Thank you very much - this  works the way it should. No chances to avoid adding that extra DIV?

Comment: Its easier that way! Otherwise you could avoid adding that DIV. Instead just move that `<div class="remove">Remove</div>` just before the closing `div` of `row` element. So that it becomes `<div class="row">......<div class="remove">Remove</div></div>`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, sire!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.append_data').on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().find('.row').each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
   });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This will remove all divs ( "Remove" divs wil remain though)
Unfortunatey -not what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: just add a $(this).remove() before return false. and also it will just remove the row divs.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/1z40zrqt/2/

```
$('.append_data').on('click', '.remove', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).parent().empty();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This code will remove ALL divs at once
Thank you - not what I am looking for. Akhilesh (answer above) made it nearly perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

How about this-

```
$('.append_data').on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
  //alert('boom');
  $('.row').remove();
  $('.remove').remove();

  return false;
});
```

Comment: This removes all added divs. This wont do, even though I am garteful for the suggestion

Comment: @Rossitten: the accepted answer too removes all divs.